# Casting generic type object

Tags: java, generics

I came across this type of casting on [java oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html)

```
 for (WatchEvent<?> event: key.pollEvents()) {
...
...
 WatchEvent<Path> ev = (WatchEvent<Path>)event;
```

My understanding that since the event reference generic type is defined as anything extend Object, so it's self-explained that since Path extends Object indirectly.

But I have searched on java specification about any rules of casting generic type that explains the above case and all related cases but I didn't find anything.

First, is my explanation is right?
Second, is there any reference or DOC about this and similar cases?

Comment: I can't tell which part is not making sense to you or what your actual question is.

Comment: If I remember correctly, casting happens at runtime, but Generics are [erased](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) at compile-time - which would explain why you can't find anything in the JLS on casting Generics (provided I'm right)...

Comment: @takendarkk , it'a apparent from the title of the question, it's the casting, and I pasted it on the question, it's casting WatchEvent<?> event to WatchEvent<Path>.

Comment: I can see that line of code, I don't understand which part of it is confusing to you.

Comment: I’m not sure what the Java team was thinking when they wrote that cast, considering `Path filename = (Path) event.context();` *is* a safe cast.

Comment: @VGR I don't think you read my questions well, first I didn't write that line of code, second I don't consider it that it's good to write, and finally look at my question, I just saw that on oracle tutorial and I was wondering about if there is any java specification written about that type of casting!

Comment: Actually, you didn’t read my comment well.  “not sure what the Java team was thinking” was putting the blame on the Java team, not you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're essentislly asking about this:

```
WatchEvent<?> event;
WatchEvent<Path> ev = (WatchEvent<Path>)event;
```

This is a *unsafe* cast.

The object returned from the poll is an unbounded type. The programmer "knows" the actual type and has (blindly) made the cast.

See [JLS 5.1.10](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html) for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Because `WatchEvent<Object>` is not a superclass of `WatchEvent<Path>`, but `WatchEvent<?>` (which may be thought of as a shorthand for `WatchEvent<? extends Object>`) is a superclass of `WatchEvent<Path>`.

Although this may seem counterintuitive at first, it is necessary to use wildcards (`?`) in this manner to preserve the type safety that generics provide.

Consider what would happen if you assign a `List<String>` to a `List<Object>` reference. Then you would be allowed to `add(new Object())`, violating the type safety.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2745301/7098259 and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/unboundedWildcards.html